# User in any time zone enters a date in Pacific Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

OK maybe I'm being exceptionally dense about this... but I'm wondering how I can make it so that users worldwide in any time zone who use a time picker to enter a time in Pacific Time, and then see it printed back to them in Pacific Time (either PST or PDT, depending) after save. Let's take the example of someone in New York. I'm thinking the flow should be like this:

1. On the input field, this person selects "1pm" (meaning 1pm Pacific Time)
2. The JS reads it as 1pm Eastern Time, converts that to UTC Unix timestamp
3. The UTC Unix timestamp is POSTed to database
4. On the show result, the timestamp is converted to Pacific Time. However you see there's now obviously the problem that the Pacific Time will read "10am" because the POSTed timestamp was for an Eastern time

Comment: What's your input format? Is it just a select drop down? If so, what's the value of the select options.

Comment: Also, is it just an hour or can you have minutes, day, month as well? What day are you picking the time for?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you could use the following function:

```
function convertUtcToPacificTime(utcDate) {
    var timezoneOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

    // set the time back 7 hours for PDT or 8 hours for PST
    // from the current utc date
    utcDate.setTime(utcDate.getTime()-(timezoneOffset/60)*3600*1000);
}
```

`.getTimezoneOffset()` retrieves the difference between the current timezone and UTC in minutes, hence why I'm dividing by 60. In PDT the function would return 420, while in PST 480 (7 and 8, respectively, when divided by 60).

Your HTML select box could look as follows:

```
<select class="time-select">
   <option value="<!-- timestamp for 1 pm UTC -->">1 pm</option>
   <option value="<!-- timestamp for 2 pm UTC -->">2 pm</option>
   ...
</select>
```

Once you get the timestamp that the user selected, you can convert it using the function above:

```
$('.time-select').change(function() {
   var timestamp = $(this).val();
   var date = new Date(timestamp);
   if (!isNaN(date)) { // check if date is valid
       convertUtcToPst(date);

       // the 'date' var now contains
       // the PST date of the selected timestamp

       // post the timestamp to the DB  
   } else {
       // handle invalid date scenario
   }
});
```

Also, to compute the UTC timestamp just call `.getTime()` on a JS Date object.

Comment: how would you deal with PST vs PDT? It's sometimes 8, sometimes 7

Comment: @james I adjusted my answer, please take a look and let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, your problem would be solved if you can change the time zone in the date you already have (built from the time picker) that is in local (whatever it is) to Pacific Time.

Using [moment](http://momentjs.com/) and [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone), you can do that with the following:

```
function convertLocalToPst(localDate) {
  var pacific = moment().tz('US/Pacific');
  var m = moment(moment(d).utc().format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm"));

  m = pacific.isDST() ? m.utcOffset('-0800') : m.utcOffset('-0700');
  return m.toDate();    
}
```